# How to send a Decimal number "545.20" and remove double quotes and send 545.20

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I want to remove double quotes from a scope value EX: "545.20" and send the value to backend like EX: 545.20

Can any one suggest me how to achive it.

Comment: How are you sending now?

Comment: `parseFloat("545.20")`

Comment: parseFloat("545.20")

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parseFloat` function before send the value to backend.

```
var value = parseFloat("545.20");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// You have x, according to your question description.
var x  = '"545.20"';          // A string of "545.20" (8 characters)
var x2 = x.replace(/"/g, ''); // A string of 545.20   (6 characters)
var x3 = parseFloat(x2);      // A floating point number of 545.20   (You can do math with this)
```